# PHP / Laravel - Get JSON input from request, dynamically match on name

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am currently getting data from an external application, by using Laravel in my app.

I have created a simple webhook in my controller file, like:

```
public function webhook(Request $request)
{
        $document = new Document();

        $document->fill($request->all());

        //Insert (or update existing) data in our database.
        $document::updateOrCreate(
            ['booking_reference' => $document->booking_reference],
            $document->getAttributes()
        );

        return response()->json('OK');
}
```

Now my problem is, I have to insert this data in a table. In order to do this, the received json objects should match the name of my table columns. I am able to set the json names in the external application - **however**, sometimes the external application add child elements to the json names.

For example, imagine this is my database:

```
id    |   booking_reference   | shipment_reference
```

And my JSON have these:

```
"booking_reference"  : "32000"
"shipment_reference" : "TREXOOO"
```

Then the data will be inserted correctly in my database. However as mentioned, the JSON objects can sometimes look like this:

```
"booking_reference_0"  : "32000"
"shipment_reference_5" : "TREX000"
```

In this example, my table will not be updated, since the JSON names does not match my table names.

How can I do, so I dynamically can insert the data in my table? The data will always have the prefix of the table name like `booking_reference` or `booking_reference_{child}`

**Update:**

Using Erubiel's answer, I can get the columns to dynamically match the name. However, I have a basic belongsTo relation setup, but solution by Erubiel strips the $document object, and only adds the *mapped* columns.

```
$document->creator()->associate(auth()->user());
```

and in my model:

```
public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

But my JSON response does not contain any `user_id` or `creator` info:

```
{"booking_reference":"CDK10000","pickup_location":"Afhentingsadresse 100 2650","drop_off_location":"Leveringsadresse 200 1000","comments":"HaHA","shipment_referenec":"SBRY100000"}
```

If I just get the `$document`, before the foreach loop:

```
{"user_id":1,"creator":{"id":1,"name":"Oliver","email":"oliver@example.com","created_at":"2018-08-27 10:58:10","updated_at":"2018-08-27 10:58:10"}}
```

**Final edit, with solution**

Using Erubiel's answer, I just modified it a bit to store the new values in my existing JSON object:

```
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
     $newKey = preg_replace("/(_?\d+)+$/", '', $key); //this generates the name of column that you need
     $document->$newKey = $value;
 }
```

Which works like a charm - output:

```
{"user_id":1,"booking_reference":"CDK10000","pickup_location":"Afhentingsadresse 100 2650","drop_off_location":"Leveringsadresse 200 1000","comments":"HaHA","shipment_referenec":"SBRY100000","creator":{"id":1,"name":"Oliver","email":"oliver@example.com","created_at":"2018-08-27 10:58:10","updated_at":"2018-08-27 10:58:10"}}
```

Comment: **however, sometimes the external application add child elements to the json names.**

Is it possible for you to take action on this external application ? It seems like  a better idea than opening your application to inconsistency

Comment: Unfortunately not - the only consistency from the external application is that the names will always come first and then it will dynamically add to that name if needed, like `shipment_reference_XXX`

Comment: I see, then you'll need some pre-processing, did you try using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)  to check if they key exists and matches what the external application returns ? It would check if substring is present in string

Comment: can you add a screen shot of how the dd($document) looks like after fill ?

Comment: something like `strpos($bookingReferenceKey, $validBookingReferenceKey)`, where bookingReferenceKey would be the key returned by the json, and validbookingReferenceKey would be `booking_reference`

Comment: @Dinosan0908 but how would I set the `$bookingReferenceKey` and `$validBookingReference`? Since the JSON names can be up to 20 different values followed by a child name.

Comment: you can add fillable property in your document model. So you can catch MassAssignmentException on field mismatch and run addition preg_match logic in this case.

Comment: @SergeyShuryakov Do you mind providing a simple example of this? I just want to make sure I do it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, as suggested on the comments, preprocess.

```
public function webhook(Request $request)
{

    $arrAux = array();
    foreach($request->all() as $key => $value){
        $newKey = preg_replace("/(_?\d+)+$/","",$key); //this generates the name of column that you need
        $arrAux[$newKey] = $value;
    }

    //Insert (or update existing) data in our database.
    Document::updateOrCreate(
        ['booking_reference' => $arrAux['booking_reference']],
        $arrAux
    );

    return response()->json('OK');
}
```

Comment: This approach requires me to "map" all the values from the JSON - which can be a lot. I need a way to do it dynamically

Comment: Should i access it using  `$doc` or `$document` after the loop?

Comment: Btw. this gives me "Invalid argument supplied for foreach" - on this `($doc as $key => $value)`

Comment: It leaves the JSON objects NULL

Comment: Just one last edit, using an array. this should work according to laravel updateOrCreate documentation.

Comment: sorry dude, writing here is difficult, i checked on ide on last edit, should be ok now.

Comment: This works pretty nice actually! Just one thing - I have a `belongsTo` relation, which I assign like this: `$document->creator()->associate(auth()->user());`- this is not added the object. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I modified your answer a bit, and kept the JSON object instead of array in the foreach loop. It works like a charm now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to resolve problem seems like architecture/design anti-pattern (insert's based on raw json data). That's not answer to your question but only my opinion.

The quickest solution to Your problem seems be a class which will accept $jsonKey and translate it/return $dbKey.

Your current code:

```
$document->fill($request->all());
```

New approach:

```
$input = $this->translator->fromInput($request->all());
$document->fill($input);
```

Example sanitize/translate class:

```
class Translator {
    /**
     * @param array $input
     * @return array
     */
    public function fromInput(array $input): array
    {
        $translated = [];

        foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
            switch ($key){
                case 'a':
                case 'a_1':
                    $translated['a'] = $value;
                    break;
                case mb_strpos($key, 'b'):
                    $translated['b'] = $value;
                    break;
                default: $translated[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $translated;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `translator` and `fromInput` in this example?

Comment: @oliverbj translator is a class with method fromInput , please see updated post

Answer (score 0):

Add protected `$fillable` property with list of available fields to mass assign to your model:

```
protected $fillable = ['booking_reference','shipment_reference'];
```

Then catch mismatch field error in your controller

```
try {
    $document->update($request->input());
} catch (MassAssignmentException $e) {
    $data = $request->input();
    foreach ($data as &$field) {
       preg_match('~([a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)+)~', $field, $match);
       $field = $match[1];
    }
    $document->update($data);
}
```

Comment: When receiving the API from the external application, above code always stop at the `try{$document->update($request->input());` - however, it will just *remove* the objects that contain child elements (or elements that it cannot find I guess). I have added the fillables to my model too.

Comment: It never runs the `catch(MassAssignmentException $e)`